# Google Calendar watch sends message only once

Tags: google-cloud-platform, calendar

I am trying to watch a calendar for meeting updates.
I've done those steps:

1. Created a service account for my project, created credentials json file and downloaded it.
2. Assigned "Pub/Sub Admin" and "Service Account Token Creator" roles to it
3. Enabled Google Calendar and Pub/Sub APIs
4. Wrote a python script to create a topic and do the watch (below)
5. Shared my calendar with the 'service account'

my script:

```
credentials_file = 'path_cred_file.json'

# Define a list of user email addresses whose calendars you want to monitor
user_email = 'myname@domain.com'

# Create a service account client
calendar_credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    credentials_file, scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']
)
calendar_service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=calendar_credentials)

pubsub_credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    credentials_file, scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']
)
pubsub_service = build('pubsub', 'v1', credentials=pubsub_credentials)

# Create a Pub/Sub topic for the user
topic_cust_name = f'watch-{user_email.replace("@", "-").replace(".", "-")}'
topic_name = f'projects/{pubsub_credentials.project_id}/topics/{topic_cust_name}'
topic = pubsub_service.projects().topics().create(name=topic_name).execute()

# Set up the push notification channel
request = {
    'id': f'{topic_cust_name}-watching',
    'type': 'web_hook',
     'address': 'my-end-point'
    }

# Create the channel and associate it with the user's calendar
channel = calendar_service.events().watch(calendarId='primary', body=request).execute()
```

My problem:
When I do an update in my calendar, I can see a request coming in to my HTTP server as expected. But, this works only once. Any other change I do on my calendar does not send a request.
What is wrong or missing?